# How to add id to items when using v-for in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a data table and when I render those records on the website, I will add ids to the elements, each element is a different id(id="item-first"), so what to do?

```js
 <div class="" v-for="(item, index) in producthots" :key="index">
          <div
            :class="
              index % 2 == 0 ? 'product-item row-reverse' : 'product-item'
            "
          >
```

I want when rendered, each element will have an id object

Comment: You want to add `ID` attribute in the the conditional class div right ? and you need id as an object. Not sure why you need `ID` as an object. If that is a case you need to stringify JSON and it is same like you provide class.

Comment: So is it possible to use :id as :class in VueJS?

Comment: You can use `:id="idVariable"` this way  you can add dynamic id to your html property

Comment: @BinChanhKun yes, you can use id like this

Comment: @BinChanhKun yes as @nur-riyad said `:id="item.name"`.  This is just an example you can use any property if item is an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for adding id you can **bind it** as like as **:src** and **:class**, it would be like this **:id** look at the example below:

```
<div :id="'CollapseState' + index" aria-expanded="false" 
class="ChangeState bg-white collapse"></div>
```

I binded the id and also for making it uniq I added **+ index** end of it so the short answer is below code:

```
:id="'CollapseState' + index"
```